# Bounded subsets. what is this question asking?

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

For a subset $A$ of $\mathbb{R}$ define $-A=\{-x : x \in A\}$. Suppose that S is a non-empty bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}$

Prove:

1) $-S$ is bounded below

2) $\inf(-S)=-\sup(S)$

3) From (2) conclude that the greatest upper bound property implies the least upper bound property

I am not looking for answers is $S$ supposed to be $-A$? The wording of the question is confusing

Comment: No, The first part using $A$ is only to explain to you what the notation negative of a set means. The actual question is what it says. You're given a non-empty bounded subset $S$ of real numbers. You're then supposed to prove the three things.

Comment: Also, (3) seems to have a wording error. It should be greatest LOWER bound

Comment: "$-A=-x : x \in A$" makes no sense. You should at least copy the problem correctly.

Comment: "From b conclude that..." but there is no "b"!

Comment: I did copy it down correctly check the link http://home.iitk.ac.in/~psraj/mth101/practice-problems/pp1.pdf

Comment: So given the fact it is written correctly what is S?